# How to generate a survey questionnaire in LaTeX? (Best: machine-readable)

Tags: questionnaire

I am searching for a ways to get a "randomised" questionnaire. It basically should be a pen-and-paper interview questionnaire for a survey.

With randomisation I mean having certain scale end points randomised (either "I totally agree is far right or far left and v.v. for I totally disagree".)

So far I only found SDAPS which I cannot use (I have a Mac and no admin password, so I cannot use this).

Does anyone else does survey research with LaTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use SDAPS without admin password?  I have used it on Linux without admin password before.

Comment: Well actually I can't get all the dependencies loaded down, as I only have a Mac (this is part of my job, so I need to use my employers IT infrastructure). But SDAPS would solve my problem, Henri? Thank you.

Comment: I'll take a look at this when I'm in the office, where I have access to a Mac.  No promises though.

Comment: No Promise needed, thanks a lot for taking a look!

Comment: Just note that I have no admin rights on that Mac :(

Comment: Me neither.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75727/discussion-between-user82729-and-henri-menke).

Comment: I opine that (in general) a typesetting program, such as TeX, is not best for creating machine-readable products. Rationale: TeX does things such as kerning, ligatures, and possibly other tweaks that improve appearance but decrease machine readability.

Comment: You might be right:(